# How to find height between parant div top to child div top in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Here, I have two div and parent div inside child div, and this child div is dynamic and scrollable so I want to find height distance between them using javascript how it is possible ? (I tried using below code and printed console but in console I got height 0)

```js
const parentDiv = document.getElementById('parent-div-id');
const childDiv = document.getElementById('child-div-id');
console.log('childDiv', childDiv.offsetTop);
```

```html
<div id="parent-div-id">
   <div id="child-div-id">
      Some content..
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can get offset().top of both the elements and taking difference of both top values  will give you the height between child and parent top

Comment: Do you want to compare the height of the parent and child div? Or do you want to know the space between the tops of the parent and child div?

Comment: @Geshode I want to know the space between the top of the parent and child div

Comment: Then Pushprajsinh Chudasama`s answer should be able to help you, if you use jQuery.

Comment: You get 0, if there is no difference between child div top and parent div top. And in your code, there doesn't seem to be a difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do it with `jQuery`

```
$('#parent-div-id').offset().top - $('#child-div-id').offset().top ;
```

For more information , Visit  https://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: Assuming, that he wants to have the positive value of the difference, it might be better to switch parent and child div around.

Answer (score 2):

**I think this is what you want**

```
document.getElementById('child-div-id').offsetHeight
```

Comment: get height including padding and border

Comment: But I found result 0 not found space between both div

Answer (score 0):

If a plain JS version is needed instead of jQuery:

```
const parentTop = window.scrollY + document.querySelector('#parent-div-id').getBoundingClientRect().top
const childTop = window.scrollY + document.querySelector('#child-div-id').getBoundingClientRect().top

const difference = childTop - parentTop
```

If you want to have the negative value of the difference, then just switch `parentTop` and `childTop` in the `difference`.